# Error for apt-get install when running Ubuntu 12.04 on flash drive

Tags: virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a memory stick courtesy of LiveLinux - http://www.linuxliveusb.com/

So I wanted to install git (`sudo apt-get install git`) and I've been getting the following error message;

```
W: Invalid regular expression '\.dpkg......
(more stuff about invalid regular expression)
E: Unable to locate package update
```

I can't do apt-get anything sudo give me the following;

```
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 0
sudo: no valid sudoers source found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I'm pretty clueless here. Any ideas?

Comment: Still need an answer?